# WP8 Bind data in a second view

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, viewmodel, bind

I am creating a wp8 app. I have two Views and two viewmodels:

VMMainPage vmMainPage -> MainPage.xaml 
VMresortInfo vmResortInfo -> resortInfo.xaml

The first one is working fine. However, I am having problems when I try to bind the second view with its viewmodel.

First, in my App.xaml.cs, I have initialized the vmResortInfo as I have done with the vmMainPage.

```
    private static VMresortInfo vmResortInfo = null;
    public static VMresortInfo VmResortInfo
    {
        get
        {
            if (vmResortInfo == null)
            {
                vmResortInfo = new VMresortInfo();
            }
            return vmResortInfo;
        }
    }
```

Then, in resortInfo.xaml.cs I changed the datacontext of the view:

```
    public resortInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.VmResortInfo;

    }
```

And finally, I try to bind the view with the viewmodel as follows:

```
       <phone:PivotItem Header="info">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding resort}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>              
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

The VMresortInfo is:

```
public class VMresortInfo
{
    private Resort resort {get; set;}

    public VMresortInfo()
    {
        this.resort = new Resort();
        this.resort.name = "NAME";
        this.resort.status = "abierta";
        this.resort.imageURL = new Uri("/Assets/fm.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }

    public void setName(string resortNameSelected)
    {
            this.resort.name = resortNameSelected;
    }
}
```

But when I run the app.. no info is shown.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Omg... I was complicating myself unnecessary...

```
        <phone:PivotItem Header="info">                          
            <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                   <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding resort.name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding resort.status}"/>
                    </StackPanel>              
            </Grid>                
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

Regards